# Cleaning text in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, text, data-cleaning

I have a data frame that has a text column that needs to be cleaned.

here is the column info

[data frame info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmBF7.png)

def process is meant to remove punctuation, convert to lower case, remove stop-word, and word stemming.

```
    
    text = text.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))  #remove punctuation
    text = [word for word in text.split() if word.lower() not in stopwords.words('english')]  #remove stopwords
    words = ""
    for i in text:  #word stemming
            stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")
            words += (stemmer.stem(i))+" "
    return words
```

However, when I apply it to the column like this.

`df['Cat_Frames'] = df['Cat_Frames'].apply(process)`

I get this error

```
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5300/294069155.py in process(text)
      1 def process(text):
      2 
----> 3     text = text.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))  #remove punctuation
      4     text = [word for word in text.split() if word.lower() not in stopwords.words('english')]  #remove stopwords
      5     words = ""

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

Also, I have another function

```
#Code to remove non-ascii characters. 
def cleandata(text):
    for punctuation in string.punctuation:
        text = text.replace(punctuation, '')
   
   
    #remove any non ASCII characters
    encoded = text.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
    decode = encoded.decode()
   
    return decode
```

I get the this error.

```
      2 def cleandata(text):
      3     for punctuation in string.punctuation:
----> 4         text = text.replace(punctuation, '')
      5 
      6 

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

these two functions were working on another dataset where the text column type were object, which is the same case in this dataset.

Can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some empty values on df['Cat_Frames'] represented by `np.nan` (`NaN`).  `NaN`  datatype is `float`, so when you attempt to use a string method it throws an error.

Check if you have NaN and, if that's the case, use `df.fillna` to change it to something else like an empty space (`' '`):

```py
df[df['Cat_Frames'].isna()] # to see if you have any rows where the value for `Cat_Frames` is `Nan`

df = df['Cat_Frames'].fillna(' ') # to change `NaN` to an empty space
```